# JavaScript "if" conditions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, dom

I am currently creating a game with HTML/SCSS and jQuery/JavaScript.

I have a character `div` that moves around when pressing keyboard arrows with jQuery. This works with an `if` statement that defines where the player can move around, so it can't get out of a bigger `div`.

I wanted to create a pure JavaScript version of the game, and the player can move around and all, except if I put the `if` statements so it doesn't get out of the border.

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz)

Here is my game (so far) with jQuery:

```js
var jQueryVersion = function() {
  var game_anim = function() {

    var level = [
      [0, 1, "l", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, "l", "l", 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3],
    ];

    var $player = $("#player");
    var $game = $("#game");

    for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {

        var n = level[i][j];

        if (n === 1) {
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "block stone ypos-0 xpos-" + [j]
          }).appendTo("#game");

        }

        if (n === 2) {
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "block stone ypos-1 xpos-" + [j]
          }).appendTo("#game");
        }
        if (n === 3) {
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "block stone ypos-2 xpos-" + [j]
          }).appendTo("#game");

        }

        if (n === 4) {
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "block stone ypos-3 xpos-" + [j]
          }).appendTo("#game");
        }

        if (n === "l") {
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "block lava ypos-" + [i] + " xpos-" + [j]
          }).appendTo("#game");
        }

      }
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(event) { // keycodes: left = 37, right = 39
      if (event.which == 39 || event.which == 68) { // right arrow or D
        if ($player.position().left < $game.width() - $player.width()) {
          $player.css("left", "+=10");
        }
      }
      if (event.which == 37 || event.which == 81 || event.which == 65) { // left arrow or Q on AZERTY or A on QWERTY
        if ($player.position().left > 0) {
          $player.css("left", "-=10");
        }
      }

      if (event.which == 38) {
        if ($player.position().top > 0) {
          $player.css("top", "-=10");
        }
      }
      if (event.which == 40) {
        if ($player.position().top < 500 - $player.height()) {
          $player.css("top", "+=10");
        }
      }

    });


  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

    game_anim();

  });
}
jQueryVersion();
```

```css
#game {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.stone {
  background-color: black;
}
.lava {
  background-color: red;
}
#player {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #3747C0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#player .eyes {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#player .eye_R {
  left: 7px;
  top: 10px;
}
#player .eye_L {
  left: 32px;
  top: 10px;
}
#player .mouth {
  height: 8.5px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: calc((50px - 32px)/2);
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-0 {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-1 {
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-2 {
  bottom: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-3 {
  bottom: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-4 {
  bottom: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-5 {
  bottom: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-6 {
  bottom: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-7 {
  bottom: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}
.ypos-8 {
  bottom: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
.xpos-0 {
  left: 0px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-1 {
  left: 50px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-2 {
  left: 100px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-3 {
  left: 150px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-4 {
  left: 200px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-5 {
  left: 250px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-6 {
  left: 300px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-7 {
  left: 350px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-8 {
  left: 400px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-9 {
  left: 450px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-10 {
  left: 500px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-11 {
  left: 550px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-12 {
  left: 600px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-13 {
  left: 650px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-14 {
  left: 700px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-15 {
  left: 750px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-16 {
  left: 800px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-17 {
  left: 850px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.xpos-18 {
  left: 900px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="game">
  <div id="player">
    <div class="eyes eye_R"></div>
    <div class="eyes eye_L"></div>
    <div class="mouth"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

As you can see, the character/player can move around, without getting out of the box.

Why won't my pure JavaScript work though?

Here is the same project with JavaScript:

```js
var javascriptVersion = function() {

 var game_anim = function() {

  var level = [
   [0, 1, "l", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, "l", "l", 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3],
  ];

  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  var game = document.getElementById("game");

  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {

    var n = level[i][j];

    if (n === 1) {

     var blocks = document.createElement("div");
     blocks.classList.add("block", "stone", "ypos-0", "xpos-" + j);
     game.appendChild(blocks);

    }

    if (n === 2) {
     var blocks = document.createElement("div");
     blocks.classList.add("block", "stone", "ypos-1", "xpos-" + j);
     game.appendChild(blocks);
    }
    if (n === 3) {
     var blocks = document.createElement("div");
     blocks.classList.add("block", "stone", "ypos-2", "xpos-" + j);
     game.appendChild(blocks);
    }

    if (n === 4) {
     var blocks = document.createElement("div");
     blocks.classList.add("block", "stone", "ypos-3", "xpos-" + j);
     game.appendChild(blocks);
    }

    if (n === "l") {
     var blocks = document.createElement("div");
     blocks.classList.add("block", "lava", "ypos-0", "xpos-" + j);
     game.appendChild(blocks);
    }

   }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { // keycodes: left = 37, right = 39
   if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) { // right arrow or D
    if (player.style.left < game.style.width - player.style.width) {
     left += 10;
     player.style.left = (parseInt(left) + left) + "px";
    }
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 81 || event.keyCode == 65) { // left arrow or Q on AZERTY or A on QWERTY
    if (player.style.left > 0) {
     left -= 10;
     player.style.left = (parseInt(left) + left) + "px";
    }
   }

   if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    if (player.style.top > 0) {
     top -= 10;
     player.style.left = (parseInt(top) + top) + "px";
    }
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    if (player.style.top < (500 - player.style.height)) {
     top += 10;
     player.style.left = (parseInt(top) + top) + "px";
    }
   }

  });

 }
 game_anim();
}

javascriptVersion();
```

```css
#game {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.stone {
  background-color: black;
}

.lava {
  background-color: red;
}

#player {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #3747C0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#player .eyes {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#player .eye_R {
  left: 7px;
  top: 10px;
}
#player .eye_L {
  left: 32px;
  top: 10px;
}
#player .mouth {
  height: 8.5px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: calc((50px - 32px)/2);
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-0 {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-1 {
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-2 {
  bottom: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-3 {
  bottom: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-4 {
  bottom: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-5 {
  bottom: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-6 {
  bottom: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-7 {
  bottom: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-8 {
  bottom: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.xpos-0 {
  left: 0px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-1 {
  left: 50px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-2 {
  left: 100px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-3 {
  left: 150px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-4 {
  left: 200px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-5 {
  left: 250px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-6 {
  left: 300px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-7 {
  left: 350px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-8 {
  left: 400px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-9 {
  left: 450px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-10 {
  left: 500px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-11 {
  left: 550px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-12 {
  left: 600px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-13 {
  left: 650px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-14 {
  left: 700px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-15 {
  left: 750px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-16 {
  left: 800px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-17 {
  left: 850px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-18 {
  left: 900px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<div id = "game">
 <div id = "player">
  <div class = "eyes eye_R"></div>
  <div class = "eyes eye_L"></div>
  <div class = "mouth"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which conditions has not working? there are many if conditions so.

Comment: @RaghavRangani the ones defining if the player is in the box

Comment: With a quick look at the code, it looks like you're retrieving element's style object before it has any value. Note, that values from stylesheets are not inherited to element's inline styles.

Comment: `style.top` etc might not be a number?

Comment: It would help if you created a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Teemu should I use `parseFloat`?

Comment: Not necessary, you need to set a value to `player.style.left` etc. before reading it. In jQuery `.css()` reads a style value using `window.getComputedStyle` if there's no inline style value available, in vanilla JS there's no such check when reading values from inline style object.

Comment: Just a sidenote: If you're interested in experimenting with simple games like this, have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html It has some very usefull patterns for things like collision detection and world generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer by *Danny Drinkwater* pointed out, `player.style.left` is not the same as `$player.position().left`. The javascript equivalent would be `element.offsetLeft`. There are also a couple of more places where you don´t get the same value as in jquery.

Below is an example of your keydown handler implemented in [vanilla js](http://vanilla-js.com/).

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) { // right arrow or D
    if (player.offsetLeft < game.getBoundingClientRect().width - player.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
      left = player.offsetLeft + 10;
      player.style.left = left.toString() + "px";
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 81 || event.keyCode == 65) { // left arrow or Q on AZERTY or A on QWERTY
    if (player.offsetLeft > 0) {
      left = player.offsetLeft - 10;
      player.style.left = left.toString() + "px";
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    if (player.offsetTop > 0) {
      top = player.offsetTop - 10;
      player.style.top = top.toString() + "px";
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    if (player.offsetTop < (500 - player.getBoundingClientRect().height)) {
      top = player.offsetTop + 10;
      player.style.top = top.toString() + "px";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Its all yours. :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *console.log* on the values of the vars you're checking against in the *if* statements on each event listener, to make sure the values are the same between your jQ and JS versions?

For example:

Does **player.style.left** in the JS version return the same value as **$player.position().left** in the jQ version?

Also, does **event.which** return the same value as **event.keyCode** between the two versions, things like that.